# Embed jqPlot into ExtJs Panel

Tags: jquery, extjs, jqplot

When I'm using jqplot it magically injects the plot into the specified div chart1:

```
var chart1 = $.jqplot('chart1', weeks , {...
```

the same is true for ExtJs which injects the created code into the 'info' div:

```
var testPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    title: "Test",
});
testPanel.render('info');
```

But how can I plot chart1 into the panel? The following html does not work:

```
<div id="info">            
    <div id="chart1" class="plot" style="width:400px;height:260px;"></div>
</div>
```

Also putting the html into extjs does not work because the html of chart1 is null (at this point!?):

```
var testPanel = new Ext.Panel({
  title: "Test",
  html: $('chart1').html()
});
testPanel.render('info');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to set a listener on the panel instance to listen to the `render` event and then plot your chart to the body of the panel.

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisramakers/ZXDru/

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    new Ext.Panel({
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        frame: true,
        title: 'Test panel',
        height: 250,
        listeners: {
            render: function(){

                // this.body.dom is the raw dom object of the body element of this panel
                // render your plot to this.body.dom
                console.log(this.body.dom)
                this.body.update('This is the new content');
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. Now I know how to make the timing for extjs correct. But I'll have to investigate how to make jqplot plotting in there. The simple approach does not work: var chart1 = $.jqplot(this.body.dom, weeks , {

Comment: If you bind the plot function to a button that renders the plot into the body, not do it onload or render of the panel? does that work?

Comment: hmmh, the html code for 'chart1' is under the 'info' div (for the panel) then, but the chart and the panel will be displayed separatly (the panel has a button without text in it then ). The panel is under the chart ...

Comment: cool, don't know if this is the correct approach, but I only needed to adapt your solution. So simply call in the render method:
 $(this.body.dom).append($('#chart1'));